# i download package composer require laraveldaily/laravel-invoices, but it comes out like this,

Tags: laravel-9, dompdf, laravel-filament

$ composer require laraveldaily/laravel-invoices
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laraveldaily/laravel-invoices
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- alperenersoy/filament-export is locked to version v0.3.5 and an update of this package was not requested.
- alperenersoy/filament-export v0.3.5 requires barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^0.8.5 -> found barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v0.8.5, v0.8.6, v0.8.7] but the package is fixed to v2.0.1 (lock file version) by a partial
update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laraveldaily/laravel-invoices:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laraveldaily/laravel-invoices:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Answer (score 1):

composer require alperenersoy/filament-export:^3.0.3-beta

try that, that's working on filament v3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).